# try-runtime error exceeded max limit of 15728640

Tags: try-runtime

I am receiving the following error when I run try-runtime:

```
[2023-10-28T09:07:02Z ERROR remote-ext] Error = Call(Custom(ErrorObject { code: ServerError(-32702), message: "Response is too big", data: Some(RawValue("Exceeded max limit of 15728640")) }))
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Input("rpc get_storage failed.")', cli/main.rs:334:6
```

Here are the full logs:

```
try-runtime --runtime target/debug/wbuild/kitchensink-runtime/kitchensink_runtime.wasm on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://localhost:9944
[2023-10-28T09:07:01Z INFO  remote-ext] replacing ws:// in uri with http://: "http://localhost:9944" (ws is currently unstable for fetching remote storage, for more see https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpsee/issues/1086)
[2023-10-28T09:07:01Z INFO  remote-ext] since no at is provided, setting it to latest finalized head, 0x5778d49a8c226ae6df4cc6b78376b0b7de6495aa0246498a3deec67078151b97
[2023-10-28T09:07:01Z INFO  remote-ext] since no prefix is filtered, the data for all pallets will be downloaded
[2023-10-28T09:07:01Z INFO  remote-ext] scraping key-pairs from remote at block height 0x5778d49a8c226ae6df4cc6b78376b0b7de6495aa0246498a3deec67078151b97
✅ Found 380 keys (0.01s) [00:00:00] 
✅ Downloaded key values 1,193.3986/s [=====================================================] 380/380 (0s) [2023-10-28T09:07:02Z WARN  remote-ext] key StorageKey([58, 99, 111, 100, 101]) had none corresponding value.
✅ Inserted keys into DB (0.00s)
[2023-10-28T09:07:02Z INFO  remote-ext] adding data for hashed prefix: , took 0.48s
[2023-10-28T09:07:02Z INFO  remote-ext] adding data for hashed key: 3a636f6465
[2023-10-28T09:07:02Z ERROR remote-ext] Error = Call(Custom(ErrorObject { code: ServerError(-32702), message: "Response is too big", data: Some(RawValue("Exceeded max limit of 15728640")) }))
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Input("rpc get_storage failed.")', cli/main.rs:334:6
```

##### Step to reproduce

Install try-runtime-cli

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli --locked
```

Clone polkadot-sdk and compile:

```
cargo build --features try-runtime
```

Run the node:

```
./target/debug/substrate-node --dev
```

Run try-runtime:

```
try-runtime --runtime target/debug/wbuild/kitchensink-runtime/kitchensink_runtime.wasm on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://127.0.0.1:9944
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your node with flags `--rpc-max-request-size 1000` and `--rpc-max-response-size 1000`